# rails form_helper could not find path for model in edit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have **`Picture`** model it contain 2 fields **photo and description (photo is field from papperclip gem)**

and I have **`PicturesController`** contain new create edit update destroy and show

I already declare in `routes.rb` by using `resource :pictures` and there is my routes.

```rb
     pictures POST   /pictures(.:format)      pictures#create
 new_pictures GET    /pictures/new(.:format)  pictures#new
edit_pictures GET    /pictures/edit(.:format) pictures#edit
              GET    /pictures(.:format)      pictures#show
              PUT    /pictures(.:format)      pictures#update
              DELETE /pictures(.:format)      pictures#destroy
```

There is my view code

```
  # pictures/new.html.erb & pictures/edit.html.erb 
  <%= form_for @picture, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>

      <div><%= f.label :photo %><br/>
        <%= f.file_field :photo %></div><br/>

      <div><%= f.label :description %><br/>
        <%= f.text_area :description %></div><br/>

      <%= f.submit :upload %>
  <% end %>

  #
```

I using same code in new and edit just change submit button label.

In `new.html.erb` is work fine(create and save picture into database).

But the error is appear in `edit.html.erb`

```
 undefined method `picture_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f830e93ad30>:0x007f830e92d5b8>
```

I already inspect `@picture`. Why rails can't find update path for Picture class?

I follow form_for guide by this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#relying-on-record-identification).

Any Idea? Thanks.

Comment: Add the code for the `new` and `edit` actions please.

Comment: @Thilo The problem is in my routes. Thank you for answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is wrong with your pluralization. With resources :pictures you should have something like..

```
pictures     GET    /pictures(.:format)                    pictures#index
             POST   /pictures(.:format)                    pictures#create
new_picture  GET    /pictures/new(.:format)                pictures#new
edit_picture GET    /pictures/:id/edit(.:format)           pictures#edit
picture      GET    /pictures/:id(.:format)                pictures#show
             PUT    /pictures/:id(.:format)                pictures#update
             DELETE /pictures/:id(.:format)                pictures#destroy
```

note the singular on the picture element.. which would yield the dynamic picture_path method

UPDATE: change 'resource' to 'resources' in your routes file and you should be ok

Comment: Yes you right it work now. I feel dumb for a while. Thanks :D

Comment: Everyone who uses Rails has been bitten by a pluralization issue at some point ;-)

Comment: Hahaha. I agree. (fist time I found that with table name and get stuck for 2 day.) :)